# How to determine if incoming Sinch call is audio or video in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sinch

Is there are a way to determine if the incoming call is audio or video in JavaScript? I have tried `incomingCall.getDetails().isVideoOffered()` but it doesn't work.

```
callClient.addEventListener({
  onIncomingCall: function (incomingCall) {
    call = incomingCall;

    var details= call.getDetails();

    if(details.isVideoOffered()){
        alert('hi');
    }
```

Comment: i think you need to mail in callid to support, and also show how you make the call and how you configure the the sinch client.

Comment: @cjensen I am just using the JavaScript and android samples (with replacing the app key) and first I tried to make video call from android to JavaScript and then from JavaScript to JavaScript, and I still can't determine the type of incoming call..

Comment: This is the error:                                                       sinch.min.js:1 TypeError: details.isVideoOffered is not a function
    at Object.onIncomingCall (VIDEOsample.js:169)
    at c.<anonymous> (sinch.min.js:1)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c.execListener (sinch.min.js:1)
    at c.handleIncomingCall (sinch.min.js:1)
    at b.1_media (sinch.min.js:1)
    at b.handleMessage (sinch.min.js:1)
    at sinch.min.js:1
    at sinch.min.js:1
    at u.i.promiseDispatch (sinch.min.js:1)

Comment: I tried isVideoOffered without parentheses but it seems undefined